# Android gradle libraries 'failure to resolve'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, crashlytics

I'm trying to coax a number of android libraries to play nicely together but I'm becoming frustrated with the versioning system.

I've managed to get the firebase version of crashlytics working but I cannot currently get this to work well with admob:

in my app 'build.gradle' I have the following dependency section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'    
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.1'    
}
```

Which produces this error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.1
```

'16.0.4' also fails whereas '17.1.1' produces this error:

```
The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@17.1.1
```

thinking that maybe all of the dependencies need to be '17.1.1' results in gradle not finding 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.1'

I doubt I'm alone in finding this version soup somewhat opaque. Is there an easier way to ensure a set of libraries that work well together?

Comment: Have you tried add all libraries supports versions at the last realease? maybe it is the answer. Link with the latest realease versions - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

and in top level gradle file use the latest version of google play services:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Note:

You need to add the google() repo in the top level gradle file, as specified in the firebase docs and also it should be before jcenter():

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
      }


dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
   }
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
              google()
             jcenter()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, that helped. One thing for me though, the 
'com.google.gms:google-services' version was '4.2.0' for me rather than '4.0.2'

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

Also update the firebase-core library to version `16.0.4`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Comment: Although the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) indicate `play-services-ads:17.1.1` was released yesterday, I don't see it in the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads).  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Try this https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html @BobSnyder I usually check there